# CodeIgniter Routes switch URL order

Tags: codeigniter

I am struggling with this too much. I want the CodeIgniter Routes to redefine the url entered.

Say this is my url: `http://my_url.com/comp/login`

The login part is my controller, and I want the comp part to determine which comp's login page should show.

So the route should change it to `http://my_url.com/login/comp`

I have the following line, but gives me 404 Not Found error

```
$route['comp/(:any)'] = "$0/comp";
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$route['comp/(:any)'] = "$0/comp";
```

to

```
$route['login/(:any)'] = "login/index/$1";
```

I assume that function index is there in you login controller, if not specify your own.

Sample login controller is as below:

```
<?php 

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    function index($type = ''){
        echo $type;
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {
    
    function index($type = ''){
        echo $type;
        exit;
    }
}

Comment: thanx, the login controller has an index function yes.
The above works, but I want the URL to be the other way around, the URL on the users side should first be the comp then login

Comment: the comp should also be a dynamic variable, so something like `$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = "$2/index/$1";`

Comment: got it to work like this: `$route['comp/(:any)'] = "$1/index/comp";`

Comment: do you know if there is a way to check if there is a value entered after comp? if not, then it should redirect the user to the master controller

Comment: See the sample login controller I shared and see the $type variable I am taking as segment.  

You just heck like 

if(empty($type)){
      redirect('another_url'); // specify you custom url
}